# XCode 6 delta updates

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

Every time a stable release of XCode gets shipped my workflow is the same.

1. Download the XCode dmg from the apple developers download page which is at the time of XCode 6.2, a 2.58 GB download size.
2. Go to XCode -> Preferences -> Downloads and get the previous simulator, for instance i get the 7.1 one to test my app in older versions. Currently it has a size of 852 MB more or less.
3. Ultimately download the currents docsets to have full documentation.

This consume a lot of bandwidth every time that XCode release a version, even if is minor. The total size of all of this is more or less 4GBs. Too much for me since i have a relative low speed connection.

So my question is, is there a better way to approach this workflow. Does XCode supports delta updates ? if so how i get those ?
Do i need to install the simulators every time that i install/update XCode ?
I need some tips here since is crazy every time that i need to update XCode. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you download Xcode from the Mac App Store?

Comment: Yes i can, but most of the time i prefer to download manually the dmg file. App Store XCode has delta updates ?

Comment: Yes, that was the entire reason why Xcode was put on the App Store; you don't have to download the entire application that way.

Comment: Did't notice ? How much is the size more or less that you need to download between every release ?